# Declare Time - 'Conversion from type 'Timespan' to type 'integer' is not valid'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I declare my dates as the following in my code:

```
Dim DeliveryDate as Date
```

But i am now trying to declare time however i keep getting an error because i cannot get the type correct. I tried the following but get the following error: "Conversion from type 'Timespan' to type 'integer' is not valid".

```
Dim DeliveryTime as DateTime
Dim DeliveryTime as Integer
```

In my database the DeliveryTime type is set to Time(7) so i would assume there should be 'Time' which i could use to declare it, but there isnt. What is the correct type i should be using?

---

Here is my exact code. There error is `Input string was not in correct format`:

```
GraphDate4 = String.Empty 
DeliveryProducts = "{ name: 'DeliveryProducts', data: [" 
If DataReader4.HasRows Then 
    While DataReader4.Read 
        Dim DevTime As Timespan = DataReader4("DeliveryTime") 
        GraphDate4 += """" + DevilTime.ToString("d") + """," 
        DeliveryProducts += DataReader4("DeliveryProducts").ToString() + "," 
    End While 
End If
```

Comment: Isn't `TimeSpan` appropriate? That's what the compiler is suggesting.

Comment: @jv42 I have tried Timespan but it fails to build because the following error occurs: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Then you need to parse the string...

Answer (score 0):

On the client-code side of things (your vb.net code), the `Date` data type is really an alias for the `DateTime` data type, which includes a component for both date and time in the same value.

But here, it sounds like maybe you just need a TimeSpan data type, and use TimeSpan's  FromSeconds() or FromMilliseconds() methods to construct it.

Comment: GraphDate4 = String.Empty
        DeliveryProducts = "{ name: 'DeliveryProducts', data: ["


        If DataReader4.HasRows Then
            While DataReader4.Read

                Dim DevTime As Timespan = DataReader4("DeliveryTime")

                GraphDate4 += """" + DevilTime.ToString("d") + ""","
  DeliveryProducts += DataReader4("DeliveryProducts").ToString() + ","
            End While
      End If

Comment: The following code has the error: "Input string was not in a correct format."